# Does Paragon Run Speed bonus overcome Heavenly Strength

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

The Crusader has a passive called [Heavenly Strength](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/crusader/passive/heavenly-strength), which allows the player to equip a 2h weapon in one hand, but reduces max run speed by 15%.  This means that the player's runspeed is limited to only 110%, which is easily capped out with a single pair of boots (a relatively common affix).  If I have a ton of paragon points, should I bother putting any of them in runspeed, assuming I have a pair of boots giving +10% already?

In a nutshell, do paragon points placed in the + runspeed bonus allow me to overcome the debuff from Heavenly Strength, and thus letting me run at more than 110% speed?

Comment: Does it actually set maximum movement speed to 110%, or does it subtract 15% from current run speed?

Comment: It reduces the maximum movement speed, as stated in the skill description (tested this on a lvl 12 crusader).

Comment: FYI I think I have approx 55 paragon points and I have about +7% movement speed (all points in that category). I don't know why but I dumped them all into movement on all 6 of my characters. I like mobility. I *suspect* movement speed modifiers are summed and then applied, but I have no sources for that.

Comment: I think that the cap of 110% includes paragon points, so only the first 20 points are relevant and any more after that are wasted. I can test this when I get home tonight.

Comment: As of patch 2.0.5. Heavenly Strength no longer has the reduced movement speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [patch 2.0.5](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/14138344/patch-205-now-live-5-13-2014#crusader). [Heavenly Strength](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/crusader/passive/heavenly-strength) no longer has the reduced movement speed.

> Removed the movement speed penalty

Answer (score 6):

There is a 125% movement speed cap (ignoring certain shrines and some skills). The "Heavenly Strength" passive reduces this cap to 110%. It doesn't reduce your movement speed. Paragon points or gear cannot take you over that cap.

Comment: The penalty is lifted in town. This could cause confusion for some people.

Comment: Hmmm, subjective but after playing Crusader for a while I'd say it reduces running speed by 15% not the cap. Can you back up your claim?

Comment: I can guarantee that it reduces the cap rather than actual run speed (unless of course you were above 110% before activating the passive).  You can confirm this a number of ways (the stat sheet for one), but there are also blue posts on the forums regarding the matter.